# Mac Os app storyboard is saying that "id cannot be empty"?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, storyboard

I just want to get started into this and I got it all installed and was ready to start messing around on my new mac but it says id cannot be empty whenever I try to open the main.storyboard.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio for Mac is installed and what version of Xamarin.iOS is installed?

Comment: I think its build 799, I can't get a better bud as my computer is blocked to installations and I had to ask the 'tech' people to install this and they just gave us that. Anyways if there isn't a hotfix for it I might just have to ask the 'tech' people to update it or give us a newer version.

Comment: Asking for two different versions numbers, look at the versions listed in the VS4M About window (click the Show details)

Comment: Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac
Version 7.3 (build 799)

Xamarin.iOS
Version: 11.6.1.2 (Visual Studio Community)

Comment: That is an older version, Xcode 9.2 support was added was added in that release (Which version of Xcode do you have installed?), personally I would update to at least the latest stable release for Xcode and VS4M, etc..: https://releases.xamarin.com/stable-release-xcode-10/